# Firebase error after logout

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, logout

I'm currently developing a little Website with Firebase. I got a couple of HTML files and each file contains a logout button which calls the function

```
function logout(){
    auth.logout();
    console.log("logout successfull");
    location.href="index.html";
}
```

After getting redirected I tried to login again but it always failed with the following error message:

> Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown server error occurred.

It took me some time to realise that the redirection to the index page caused the problem. When I delte the location.href="index.html"; line, everything works fine. 
Problem is, I really need something that redirects me to the front page, when the user isn´t loged in. Is this a known problem and/or can someone come up with a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

PS.: I realised that I could "fix" the problem (after getting redirected to the index page) when I cause an error (f.e. calling a undefined function). Idk if this information helps...

Comment: You'll need to include a small, reproducible example here that we can use to verify and examine the behavior. Then we should be able to pinpoint the error. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for your reply Kato!
I changed quite a lot, since I started the "project". Instead of using mutliple HTML files I copied everything into the index.html and work now with mutliple (hidden) DIVs. 
But unfortunatly, the problem still exists.

I offer two different Login possibilites. One with Facebook (works 100% of the time for me) and one with the SimpleLogin (works barely).

I´m pretty sure I did the initialization the same way like it´s done in the tutorials on firebase.com.
This is how I connect to the Firebase DB

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://partyfinder-db.firebaseio.com/');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    // an error occurred while attempting login
    alert(error);
  } else if (user) {

    // Here I work with user.id etc.    


  } else {
    // user is logged out
  }

});
```

And that is how I try to login the user...

```
function login() {
    //I probably should use jQuery here...  
    var _email = document.getElementById("emailLogin").value;
    var _pw1 = document.getElementById("passwordLogin").value;
    var _rememberMe = document.getElementById("rememberMe").checked;

    auth.login('password', {
        email: _email,
        password: _pw1,
        rememberMe: _rememberMe
    });
    showMain(); //Hide and show DIVs and stuff...
}
```

I call this function on the SignIn Button. The whole Javascript file is linked in the head part of the HTML file.

So, calling this function is normally causing the following error

> Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown server error occurred.

I already figured out that this message only shows up when the connection to the DB already was successful. For example, when I type in an invalide email adress, the following message appears:

> Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin: The specified user does not exist.

There are a few things that can "fix" the problem. For example, when I use the Facebook Login and logout after this was successful, I can sign in using firebase simpleLogin. Sometimes (unfortunatly not always) it helps when I`m causing an error, f.e. calling a non existing function. After the error message is displayed in the console, I can continue logging in (successfully).

But to be honest I`ve absolutly no idea what this tells me about the error and if this is somehow a hint to the solution. I also tried to set some breaking points and debug through the relevant code (using google chrome) but didn´t find anything.

I uploaded the page to a free webspace, where you can test this whole thing by yourself.
But please note, this project is just for testing purpos. I´m not planning to release it somehow, it´s just for me to figure out multiple things and I find it easier to learn something when I can set it in a context. I´m pretty sure it´s quite bad coded and contains many mistakes, etc. But I´m always grateful for feedback beside the actual problem :)

For the login you can use

> email: user@email.com 
>   password: user

If you use the FB-Login, your Name and your email adress will be saved to the Database (but I can delete this section of the code if you want/need to use it and feel uncomfortable about it).

http://partyfinder.lima-city.de/

Most of the comments are in german, sorry for that...